# How could I do not repeat the selection process in Cypress?

Tags: testing, select, cypress, dry

How could I do not repeat the selection process in Cypress?

E.g. if I have:

```
cy
   .get("...").find("...")...eq(0)...should("...")
   .get("...").find("...")...eq(1)...should("...");
```

How could I avoid duplicating the `.get("...").find("...")...` part if at some point I need to pick either the `eq(0)` or the `eq(1)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[You can use `.as()` to alias an element.](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/as)

```js
// Just aliasing the base
cy.get('foo').find('bar').as('something');
cy.get('@something').eq(0).should('exist');
cy.get('@something').eq(1).should('exist');

// aliasing the specific elements
cy.get('foo').find('bar').eq(0).as('firstEl');
cy.get('@firstEl').should('exist');
cy.get('foo').find('bar').eq(1).as('secondEl');
cy.get('@secondEl').should('exist');
```

You could also use a custom command.

```js
// If the selectors in `get` and `find` are constant, you could do a custom command
Cypress.Commands.add('myGet', (index) => {
  return cy.get('foo').find('bar').eq(index);
})
cy.myGet(0).should('exist');

// Or if you wanted to be able to customize the get and find
Cypress.Commands.add('myGet', (get, find, index) => {
  return cy.get(get).find(find).eq(index);
})

cy.myGet('foo', 'bar', 0).should('exist');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a custom command for this. Go to `cypress/support/commands.js` and write:

```js
Cypress.Commands.add('selectElement', (index) => {
  cy.get('selector').find('selector').eq(index).should('be.visible')
})
```

And then in your test just write:

```js
cy.selectElement(1)
cy.selectElement(2)
```